# Python - two strings appear to be equal but are not

Tags: python, string, mutagen

I’m trying to figure out why two strings which appear to be equal in python are not equal. There appears to be a similar question posted [Why are my two python strings not equal in my program but equal in the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208446/why-are-my-two-python-strings-not-equal-in-my-program-but-equal-in-the-interpret) but this does not address my problem. In this above post, the problem was apparently a new line at the end of one string but not the other.

I’m writing a script to organize music files in my music collection. I’m using mutagen to read file metadata. I encounter the problem with .m4p files. I use

```
import mutagen
metadata = mutagen.File(“audio.m4p”)
```

to get a dict of the file metadata. I view the keys in the dict by

```
for key in metadata.keys(): print(key)
```

which returns

```
----:com.apple.iTunes:tool
----:com.apple.iTunes:iTunNORM
cnam
cART
aART
cwrt
calb
cgen
trkn
disk
cday
cpil
pgap
apID
cprt
cnID
rtng
atID
cmID
plID
geID
sfID
akID
stik
purd
----:com.apple.iTunes:iTunMOVI
covr
```

‘cnam’ appears to be the index of the dict item containing the title of the file. However when I try to access it with `mutagen[‘cnam’]` I get `KeyError: 'cnam'`.

Puzzled, I then assigned this key to a variable with

```
the_key = list(metadata.keys())[2]
```

to help gather information. I did the following:

```
>>> the_key=='cnam'
False
>>> the_key[0]=='c'
False
>>> the_key[1]=='n'
True
>>> the_key[2]=='a'
True
>>> the_key[2]=='m'
False
```

And below tested the equality of the copied value of `the_key` from the command line (left) and the manually typed version of what appears to be the key (right)

```
>>> 'cnam'=='cnam'
True
```

finding that they were equal.

There seems to be some sort of text formatting issue going on that I don’t understand. I assume there are characters which look the same but actually aren’t, but I can’t seem to prove this by copying and pasting.

My questions are: what is the issue here and how can I address it? I could imagine a work around involving manipulations of the dict or something else, but I would rather figure out the problem at hand.

EDIT: I was wrong in assuming that `mutagen.File` returned a dict. It returns a `<class 'mutagen.mp4.MP4'>` object.

EDIT:

```
len(the_key) 
4
```

EDIT:

```
type(the_key)
<class 'str'>
```

EDIT:

```
>>> print("<{}>".format(the_key))
<cnam>
>>> print(repr(the_key))
'cnam'
```

Comment: `>>> the_key[2]=='m'` you mean `>>> the_key[3]=='m'`... try to `strip` your keys and test the lenght. There may be spaces after the key.

Comment: try `print("<{}>".format(the_key))` or `print(repr(the_key))`

Comment: Use `ord` to reliably identify characters in a string.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that two of the characters in the key in question had "unusual" ASCII values. When I have a string 'c', python assumes I'm referring to the character with ASCII value of 99, whereas the 'c' character in the data structure created by mutagen used ASCII value 169.

I had simply to determine the ASCII values of the individual characters of the string with `ord` and use them to build the correct string for the key 'cnam' using `chr`.

```
>>> the_key == 'cnam'
False
>>> ord(the_key[0])
169
>>> ord(the_key[3])
109
>>> new_key = chr(169)+'na'+chr(109)
>>> new_key
'cnam'
>>> new_key == the_key
True
```

I did not have to check the ASCII values of the characters 'n' and 'a' because it was shown in the question that the "default" ASCII values for 'n' and 'a' already matched those of the string in question.

Comment: That was a tricky one, I had a similar problem and found out thanks to your solution

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the mutagen api:

https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html

> **class mutagen.mp4.MP4Tags**
>   Bases: mutagen._util.DictProxy, mutagen.Tags
>
> Dictionary containing Apple iTunes metadata list key/values.
>
> Keys are four byte identifiers, except for freeform (‘—-‘) keys.
>   Values are usually unicode strings, but some atoms have a special
>   structure:
>
> Text values (multiple values per key are supported):
>
> **‘\xa9nam’** – track title
>   ‘\xa9alb’ – album
>   ‘\xa9ART’ – artist 
>    etc.

```
print ( '\xa9')   #
```

**©**

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `key` variable. Keys are NOT `strings` probably.