# apparently equal strings are not equal in Python

Tags: python, string, string-comparison, gitpython

I am writing a prepush githook using GitPython.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
local_ref, local_sha1, remote_ref, remote_sha1 = [line for line in sys.stdin][0].split(' ')

for i, commit in enumerate(repo.iter_commits('docs-and-config')):

    print("remote_sha1 is {}\n".format(remote_sha1), "commit.hexsha is {}\n".format(commit.hexsha))
    print(type(remote_sha1), type(commit.hexsha))
    print(commit.hexsha == remote_sha1)
    if commit.hexsha == remote_sha1:
        remote_commit = commit
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Here is the result of the first three iterations:

```
 remote_sha1 is 9c5e0c813f8ac8bf95997911c7845aec935f1d43

 commit.hexsha is ad0632a1e17c03d65124154a7f1f8d7c23966fbf

<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
False



remote_sha1 is 9c5e0c813f8ac8bf95997911c7845aec935f1d43

 commit.hexsha is e63f31ba923dca63917c1ed3a9d332f9c42baf83

<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
False



remote_sha1 is 9c5e0c813f8ac8bf95997911c7845aec935f1d43

 commit.hexsha is 9c5e0c813f8ac8bf95997911c7845aec935f1d43

<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
False
```

Why is the third instance not equal?  I've tried stripping whitespace from both strings; that makes no difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my two python strings not equal in my program but equal in the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208446/why-are-my-two-python-strings-not-equal-in-my-program-but-equal-in-the-interpret)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have an extra `\n` char in the strings you are parsing from stdin. 
Try to do  : `remote_sha1 = remote_sha1.strip()` in the beginning of your `for` loop.

Also, if you use `!r` as a rendering type when calling `str.format`, Python wll put `'` around your strings, so you will be aware of whitespace there:

```
print("remote_sha1 is {!r}\n".format(remote_sha1), "commit.hexsha is {!r}\n".format(commit.hexsha))
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed!  I really tried to test for the effect of stripping whitespace -- I even said so in the post.  But I think the way I did it I didn't notice that my test had actually succeeded.  Thanks for the tip about `!r`.  I'm not said I asked just so I could learn that.